# What is the intellectual import of a work of art (geistiger Gehalt) for Hegel?

Tags: hegel, critical-theory, art

What is the intellectual import of a work of art (geistiger Gehalt) for Hegel? I've not read much Hegel, and feel very unfamiliar with his ideas, but it comes up in discussions of critical theory.

Comment: See SEP. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-aesthetics/  it is all interesting but especially part 3.

Comment: This book is also good for the general area you are studying. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DZP2CGX?tag=duckduckgo-iphone-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1